# Will DNS rebinding attack still happen if browser caches the response for a long time?

Tags: dns-rebinding

In the DNS rebinding attack, if the victim’s browser caches the IP address for any hostname used in HTTP requests for an hour, can the attack still be successful? Why?

I know it is a question available in the Security course, but I did not see any satisfactory coherent answer anywhere.

Comment: Caching time cannot be seen in isolation. How your theoretical browser behaves when the previously used cached IP address can no longer be accessed? Will it simply fail for the rest of the hour, will it try alternative IP addresses it got together with the last DNS requests (i.e. IPv4 and IPv6 lookups), will it do new DNS requests, ...?